# Why does the build.gradle file appear in Android studio like this ...?

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle

Why does the **build.gradle** file appear in Android studio like this ...? SDK Dependency Sync Can't Be Synced When Connecting Firebase (In an App Building Using Java)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}



task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new Android studio the gradle structure has been changed, Used `settings.gradle` to access the repositories and the dependencies

Comment: Yes..Thanks for the help